# Cytoscape not restoring elements

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

According to the documentation (http://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.remove / http://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.restore), it is possible to restore previously removed elements from the graph, by using the `eles.restore()` method.

I am however unable to restore all elements in this facon?

```
applyElementFilters = () => {
    const excluded = [1, 2, 3];

    // Restore all elements first, this apparently does nothing
    this.cy.elements().restore();

    if (excluded && excluded.length > 0) {
        const excludedElements = this.cy
            .elements()
            .filter(element => excluded.includes(element.data("id")));

        this.cy.remove(excludedElements);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in documentation, you have save the reference of `removed` elements for restoring them.

```
// remove selected elements
var eles = cy.$(':selected').remove();

// ... then some time later put them back
eles.restore();
```

In your case when you're removing elements by doing this

```
this.cy.elements().restore();
```

you can save them in a variable or in `this` like below

```
this.__removedElements = this.cy.elements().remove();
// or
var removedElements; // global variable
removedElements = this.cy.elements().remove();
```

then you can restore them like below

```
this.__removedElements.restore()
// or
removedElements.restore()
```

Comment: Ah ha, I was certain I could just find them by using the ":removed" selector.

Comment: 1 min left! ;-)

Comment: `cy.elements()`: Get all elements in the graph.  `cy.elements().restore()`: Restore all elements already in the graph, a nop.

Comment: A `:removed` selector only makes sense to query on a set of elements that contains removed elements and non-removed elements.  So there's no point in running that on `cy.elements()`.  Having `cy.elements()` return removed elements would be like `document` containing removed DOM elements --- unintuitive and not friendly to the garbage collector.